# Despite adding __construct() i am getting error - "Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP"

Tags: php, wordpress

despite adding __construct()  , i am getting error  - Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP
Its a wordpress plugin [https://wordpress.org/plugins/datetime-now-button/]  code -

```
<?php
/*
Author: radiok
Plugin Name: Date/Time Now Button
Author URI: http://radiok.info/
Plugin URI: http://radiok.info/blog/category/datetime-now-button/
Description: Adds a Now button to the right of date and time fields.
Version: 0.2.2
Text Domain: datetime-now-button
Domain Path: /languages
*/
if ( !class_exists( 'DateTimeNowButtonPlugin' ) ) {
    class DateTimeNowButtonPlugin {
        function DateTimeNowButtonPlugin() {
            add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'InitI18n' ), 10, 1 );
            add_action( 'admin_head', array($this, 'AddNowButton' ), 10, 1 );
        }
        function InitI18n() {
            // Place your language file in the languages subfolder and name it "datetime-now-button-{language}.mo" replace {language} with your language value from wp-config.php
            load_plugin_textdomain( 'datetime-now-button', FALSE, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages' );
        }

        function AddNowButton() {
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                if (jQuery('#timestampdiv').length > 0) {
                    jQuery('#timestampdiv').find('div')
                        .append('&nbsp;')
                        .append(jQuery('<a>')
                            .attr('class', 'now button')
                            .append('<?php _e( 'Now', 'datetime-now-button' ); ?>')
                        );
                }
                if (jQuery('.inline-edit-date').length > 0) {
                    jQuery('.inline-edit-date').find('div')
                        .append('&nbsp;')
                        .append(jQuery('<a>')
                            .attr('class', 'now button')
                            .append('<?php _e( 'Now', 'datetime-now-button' ); ?>')
                        );
                }
                jQuery('.now.button').bind('click', function() {
                    <?php
                    $time_adj = current_time('timestamp');
                    $cur_mm = gmdate( 'm', $time_adj );
                    $cur_jj = gmdate( 'd', $time_adj );
                    $cur_aa = gmdate( 'Y', $time_adj );
                    $cur_hh = gmdate( 'H', $time_adj );
                    $cur_mn = gmdate( 'i', $time_adj );
                    ?>
                    if (jQuery('select[name="mm"]').length > 0) jQuery('select[name="mm"]').val('<?php echo $cur_mm; ?>');
                    if (jQuery('input[name="jj"]').length > 0) jQuery('input[name="jj"]').val('<?php echo $cur_jj; ?>');
                    if (jQuery('input[name="aa"]').length > 0) jQuery('input[name="aa"]').val('<?php echo $cur_aa; ?>');
                    if (jQuery('input[name="hh"]').length > 0) jQuery('input[name="hh"]').val('<?php echo $cur_hh; ?>');
                    if (jQuery('input[name="mn"]').length > 0) jQuery('input[name="mn"]').val('<?php echo $cur_mn; ?>');
                });
            });
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
if ( class_exists( 'DateTimeNowButtonPlugin' ) ) $date_time_now_button = new DateTimeNowButtonPlugin();
```

i tried changing `function DateTimeNowButtonPlugin()`  to `function __construct()` but still wordpress show me error - Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP . What else correction needs to be done ?? I dont want to hide the error message , i want to correct this code . What else in this could be causing that error message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right to change the method name to `__construct()`. Try declaring your method visibility like `public function __construct()` (and the same for the other methods)

```
<?php
/*
Author: radiok
Plugin Name: Date/Time Now Button
Author URI: http://radiok.info/
Plugin URI: http://radiok.info/blog/category/datetime-now-button/
Description: Adds a Now button to the right of date and time fields.
Version: 0.2.2
Text Domain: datetime-now-button
Domain Path: /languages
*/
if ( !class_exists( 'DateTimeNowButtonPlugin' ) ) {
    class DateTimeNowButtonPlugin {
        public function run() {
            add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'InitI18n' ), 10, 1 );
            add_action( 'admin_head', array($this, 'AddNowButton' ), 10, 1 );
        }

        public function InitI18n() {
            // Place your language file in the languages subfolder and name it "datetime-now-button-{language}.mo" replace {language} with your language value from wp-config.php
            load_plugin_textdomain( 'datetime-now-button', FALSE, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages' );
        }

        public function AddNowButton() {
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                if (jQuery('#timestampdiv').length > 0) {
                    jQuery('#timestampdiv').find('div')
                        .append('&nbsp;')
                        .append(jQuery('<a>')
                            .attr('class', 'now button')
                            .append('<?php _e( 'Now', 'datetime-now-button' ); ?>')
                        );
                }
                if (jQuery('.inline-edit-date').length > 0) {
                    jQuery('.inline-edit-date').find('div')
                        .append('&nbsp;')
                        .append(jQuery('<a>')
                            .attr('class', 'now button')
                            .append('<?php _e( 'Now', 'datetime-now-button' ); ?>')
                        );
                }
                jQuery('.now.button').bind('click', function() {
                    <?php
                    $time_adj = current_time('timestamp');
                    $cur_mm = gmdate( 'm', $time_adj );
                    $cur_jj = gmdate( 'd', $time_adj );
                    $cur_aa = gmdate( 'Y', $time_adj );
                    $cur_hh = gmdate( 'H', $time_adj );
                    $cur_mn = gmdate( 'i', $time_adj );
                    ?>
                    if (jQuery('select[name="mm"]').length > 0) jQuery('select[name="mm"]').val('<?php echo $cur_mm; ?>');
                    if (jQuery('input[name="jj"]').length > 0) jQuery('input[name="jj"]').val('<?php echo $cur_jj; ?>');
                    if (jQuery('input[name="aa"]').length > 0) jQuery('input[name="aa"]').val('<?php echo $cur_aa; ?>');
                    if (jQuery('input[name="hh"]').length > 0) jQuery('input[name="hh"]').val('<?php echo $cur_hh; ?>');
                    if (jQuery('input[name="mn"]').length > 0) jQuery('input[name="mn"]').val('<?php echo $cur_mn; ?>');
                });
            });
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
if ( class_exists( 'DateTimeNowButtonPlugin' ) ) {
    $date_time_now_button = new DateTimeNowButtonPlugin();
    $date_time_now_button->run();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Andy . sorry for late reply. Do you think security wise this code is okay for the wordpress plugin esp adding that `public function __construct()`  ?

Comment: I think it's fine from a security point of view. `__construct` probably shouldn't be used to add actions, I've edited my answer with `$class->run();` instead - but that's just a best practice thing. Security advice: add `esc_html_e` instead of `_e`. this just prevents XSS attacks via translation files. (e.g. `<?php esc_html_e( 'Now', 'datetime-now-button' ); ?>`). You could enqueue and localize your script  (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) if you wanted to, but not a security issue.